# Having a company Facebook account for Facebook Connect?

Tags: facebook

My company wants to include Facebook Connect into some of the web sites we sell. Getting the integrations to work properly isn't really the problem, the problem is creating the required app in a useful way.

I can create the app with my personal Facebook account, but that's no good if I quit a few years down the way, and since Facebook scrapped company accounts over Pages, it's not possible to make a company account where we can gather all the Facebook Connect apps we make.

Is there an official solution and/or working hack that will solve this problem for us?

Thanks in advance for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You are going to have to use a "real" Facebook account for this. You also need to verify that account as a Facebook developer. This involves either submitting a phone number (SMS verification) or a credit card number.

If you are worried about using your own personal account, as your client to use his. There is no reason you should be forced to use **your** account - after all, its only a job right? :)

I strongly advise against opening a new "fake" account to manage your applications. Facebook is tightening their security and methods to find these fake users. Should Facebook close this "fake" account, you won't have access to your application's settings anymore.

Comment: That's what I thought. I thought about using my boss' Facebook account, but I can see about a thousand ways that can go south.

Comment: No one should force you to use your personal account for work purposes (unless this was previously agreed upon). In the same way, you wouldn't use your personal gmail account for work emails. The idea here is that Facebook will have a "real" user to track back bad applications to.